# JDBC going extrem slow after a few big sql selects in scala

Tags: sql, scala, jdbc

atm im trying to get a lot datas(26 million entrys) out of a sql database to put them into a LevelDB.

Im using scala and a connectionPool from JDBC. This is my Query:

> "SELECT ts.block_id, ts.sender, ts.fee, ts.recipient AS transaction_recipient, ts.amount AS transaction_amount, ts.type, tf.recipient AS transfer_recipient, tf.amount AS transfer_amount FROM transactions ts LEFT OUTER JOIN transfers tf ON (tf.transaction_id = ts.transaction_id) ORDER BY ts.block_id ASC  LIMIT " + (x*sqlBatchSize) + ","+sqlBatchSize)

Where sqlbatchSize is the parameter for how much entrys I want to get in one SQL Statement and x is the iteration amount. So simply im asking select **** Limit 0,10.000  and then 10.000,10.000 and then 20.000,10.000 and so on.
I tried it with different sizes from 5k to 10k, 100k, 500k, 5kkk and so on. Tried it with some start value, so I only get the entrys from the last half of the database and stuff like that. 
I have always the same problem. The first query is fast, the second one is slower and then the next ones are slower and slower. Doenst matter if I request 10x 10k oder 10x 500k entrys. Always the same.

Here is my code a little bit shorted:

> 

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.sql.{Connection, DriverManager}
import org.apache.commons.dbcp2._
import com.google.common.primitives.Longs
import com.typesafe.config._
import scala.math.BigInt
import java.io.File
import java.util.Calendar
import org.iq80.leveldb
import org.iq80.leveldb.impl.Iq80DBFactory._
import org.iq80.leveldb.Options
object Datasource {
  // Load config
  val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
  val dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://" + conf.getString("database.db_host") + ":" + conf.getString("database.db_port") + "/" + conf.getString("database.db_name")
  val connectionPool = new BasicDataSource()
  connectionPool.setUsername(conf.getString("database.db_user"))
  connectionPool.setPassword(conf.getString("database.db_password"))
  connectionPool.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
  connectionPool.setUrl(dbUrl)
  connectionPool.setInitialSize(3)
}
object main extends App {
  var durchlaufen = 1
  var x = 0
  var sqlBatchSize = 50000
  if(durchlaufen == 1){
    try{
      var grenze = 10
      while(x < grenze) {
        val connection = Datasource.connectionPool.getConnection
        val rs = connection.createStatement.executeQuery("SELECT ts.block_id, ts.sender, ts.fee, ts.recipient AS transaction_recipient, ts.amount AS transaction_amount, ts.type, tf.recipient AS transfer_recipient, tf.amount AS transfer_amount FROM transactions ts LEFT OUTER JOIN transfers tf ON (tf.transaction_id = ts.transaction_id) ORDER BY ts.block_id ASC  LIMIT " + (x*sqlBatchSize+10000000) + ","+sqlBatchSize)
        x += 1
        while (rs.next()) {
          // Do stuff
        }
        connection.close()
        rs.close()
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

What I tried too is the remove the connection close and working on the same connection in all iterations of the while. Same result

I checked with visualVm the memory and there is one byte array that is very large and max out the ram. But I have no clue what byte array that is

Anyone has an idea why the querys start to go extrem slow?

If its like, im requestting 10x 500k entrys than the ram is full and its going to slow down, okay. I can understand that. But if I request 10x 5k it goes slow the same rate as 10x 500k just a single request takes longer. At the end, the third query takes about double the time and the 7th query takes about 6-9 times longer than the first

Comment: Did you get OutOfMemoryError eventually and JVM crash? Or your application continues to work, but slow?

Comment: Its just slow down extremly. For example, first request takes 10 mins, 2nd 20, 3rd 40 mins and after about 6h the 4th isnt finished and I stopped the programm

Comment: If you run the same query against source database via some SQL Client (not using scala or JDBC), is it getting slow with every next page as well?

Comment: Okay, tried it with PHP and I have the same problem. Same query times for same query on both languages. So its a sql problem. Any idea?

Comment: That is what I though. I believe it is SQL Query issue. `Order By` with `Limit` does not really work fast as far I remember from my past experience. Basically, what is going on is a database has to select all the records, then sort them by specified field and then cut a page. Instead, you can try incremental approach using window like some_id > last_seen_id. Last_seen_id is a state of your program. Although this question is not Scala question anymore.